# Best Practices for Creating an abstraction layer for charts library

Tags: javascript, charts, abstraction

I am working on a project where I need to use charts. I am currently using nvd3 with angular. But due to its heavy payload, I will be switching to some other chart library.

Now, I want to create an abstraction layer in js which allows me to use any charting library without changing much of code.

Now what are the best things that i can include into it to make it awesome? What are few things I should keep in mind before making an abstraction layer. I have never created any abstraction layer.

What would be best practices for creating such abstraction layer. I want to use this abstraction layer across angular, backbone and jquery projects too.

Thanks.